# hide jQuery validation message

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to disable error messages when checkbox checked. 
I wrote a script that disables some of the entry, but I do not know how to disable the error message.

My js code:

```
$().ready(
function () {
    $("#needPost").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //Need hide error Message

        } else {


        }
    }
    );
```

How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if your error message has class "checkBoxError", you may put

```
$().ready(
function () {
    $("#needPost").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(".checkBoxError").hide();
        } else {
            $(".checkBoxError").show();
        }
    }
    );
});
```

Comment: Message disappears, but when I click on the button.How to manually invoke a method of validation?

Comment: You may change 'click' to 'change' so that if you have another script that changes the values of the forms, it will automatically validate it based on your rules. You may also use it for textboxes, just put your validation rules in the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

put all error messages with class error and add this in the error hide function if checked

$('.error').hide();